# Glassfish node "no space left on device"

Tags: amazon-web-services, glassfish, space, disk

We are running a cluster of Glassfish 4.1 web nodes. There are 3 nodes, each of which contains 1 instance. This runs on AWS servers.

I have been deploying our web application to these servers for over a year now. Tonight, when I deployed, I got a "no space left on device" error referring to 1 of the web nodes and deployment failed. We cleared up some files and deployed ok.

We really need to know if deployment causes a gradual accumulation of files somewhere on a Glassfish web instance, such as logs or cached files, so that we can delete from the right place next time. The files we deleted tonight were just one-offs and that won't help next time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Turns out the GF web nodes had over 1 year of accumulated logs totalling over 500 MB on each node, so we are going to archive the old logs, turn down the loggers, and hopefully that will fix it! Thanks to all!

Comment: Try this: do a `df -k` (assuming a Unix based O/S).  Now do a deploy.  Run the `df -k` again.  Are they the very similar?

Comment: You could also use something like `du -chs /$GF_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/*` which will give you the size of each directory in your domain directory and a summary at the bottom.